# Installing app from Google Play Store gives a Firebase Authentication Error but installing the same APK from my computer works perfectly

Tags: java, android, authentication, firebase

I'm having a problem
I have an app that uses Firebase Auth to sign in with Google. I uploaded the Release APK to Google Play Store as an Alpha version but when I download it to test it on my phone it give an Authentication error, however, when I download the same apk from my computer to my phone it works perfectly.

In my main

```
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    findViewById(R.id.signIn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            signIn();
        }
    });
```

onStart:

```
 FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if(currentUser!=null)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
    }
```

```
private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}



@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);

        } else {


            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed, please try again",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                       System.out.println(task.getResult().toString());
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed, please try again",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Did you add the SHA-1 hash of your signed APK to your project in the same way you added your debug key when you first set things up?

Comment: Yes. I added both SHA-1. The weird thing is that if I install the release apk from my computer it works perfectly but if I download the same apk (the release apk of course) from the play store then it gives the error.

Comment: Do you have the play console configured to automatically sign your APK after you upload it?  https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en

Comment: No. But you really thing that would have anything to do with the fact that it gives an error when downloading from the play store? I'm using the same key every time I regenerate the release apk

Answer (score 5):

I had your same problem, and I solved it adding a new SHA-1 key in the Firebase Console. If you enable Google Play App Signing for your app, you can find the SHA-1 to add to the Firebase Console in the Google Play Developer Console.
In the console, if you open the "Release Management" section, you will find the "App signing" tab, as you can see in the image below.

[image: App signing]

In this page you will find a section called "App signing certificate", where you can see a MD5 certificate fingerprint, a SHA-1 certificate fingerprint and a SHA-256 certificate fingerprint, as you can see in the image below.

[image: MD5, SHA-1, SHA-256]

You have to copy the SHA-1 certificate fingerprint in the Firebase Console, together with the debug SHA-1 and the release SHA-1 of your Keystore.